# How to fix AEM 6.3 - Maven Archetype 12 "No DS descriptor found" errors?

Tags: maven, osgi, aem, osgi-bundle, sling

We have created an AEM 6.3 project using Maven Archetype 12. We have not yet written any code and are just trying to build the empty project imported into Eclipse.

We are getting the error which is mentioned in the documentation:
https://sling.apache.org/documentation/development/ide-tooling.html#why-do-i-get-an-error-about-no-ds-descriptor-found-at

`No DS descriptor found at path target/classes/OSGI-INF/com.xxxxxxx.core.filters.LoggingFilter.xml`

The documentation states, "*One often-occuring situation is that a Maven project using the maven-scr-plugin generates the descriptors outside of target/classes, typically in target/scr-plugin-generated. To fix this, make sure that you're using the maven-scr-plugin 1.15.0 or newer and that you have not set a custom outputDirectory.*"

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be the case with our out-of-the-box generated project. The descriptors are not being generated at all. Upgrading `maven-scr-plugin` to `1.15.0` or even `1.26.0` does not change the symptoms.

What is the proper fix for this issue?

Environment Version Info

```
Apache Maven 3.5.0 (ff8f5e7444045639af65f6095c62210b5713f426; 2017-04-03T12:39:06-07:00)
Maven home: C:\usr\apache-maven-3.5.0\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_131, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

I can reproduce the error consistently. All steps are captured in this [2-minute video](http://youtu.be/zMwQMgqOxm0)

Comment: Need some information to replicate, what's your maven/java version and how *exactly* did you generate the project? and what command did you run to get the error? please add anything else you think will be helpful to reproduce. Can you reproduce the error consistently? I.e try to create a new project the same way and get the same error ?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam yes I can reproduce the error consistently. All steps captured in this 2-minute video: https://youtu.be/zMwQMgqOxm0

Comment: java and maven version, please?

Comment: @AhmedMusallam Maven 3.5.0, Java 1.8.0_131

Comment: looks like http://repo.adobe.com/ is down... so I cannot create an archtype at this time..

Comment: Are you getting an error while running mvn clean install, or on aem? I wouldn't worry if it's only showing error in eclipse.

Comment: It shows up in Eclipse only.

Comment: Do you have a featured named  'Tycho Project Configurators' installed in Eclipse? If so, at what version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding an empty `<Export-Package></Export-Package>` worked initially, but then broke when I started writing code. Long-term fix is some combination of the following:

1. Don't use the newer OSGI `@Component` annotations, continue to use `@SlingServlet` instead.
2. Add this dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
       <artifactId>org.apache.felix.scr.annotations</artifactId>
       <version>1.12.0</version>
   </dependency>
   ```
3. Add this plug-in

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-scr-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>1.26.0</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>generate-scr-scrdescriptor</id>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>scr</goal>
                   </goals>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```
4. Not sure if this made a difference, but also upgrade to Sling IDE Tools 1.2.0

Answer (score 0):

You see this error when there is no implementation of Declarative Services in OSGI framework. Make sure you see `Apache Felix Declarative Services (org.apache.felix.scr)` bundle active and running in your felix console.

Alternatively (recommended), you can use the official annotations from OSGI R6. According to [felix docs](https://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin.html), development of the Apache Felix SCR Plugin is in maintenance mode. You don't require `mvn-scr-plugin` if you are using the official osgi annotation.

This [article](http://www.nateyolles.com/blog/2017/05/osgi-declarative-services-annotations-in-aem) should give you a jumpstart in using official annotations.

Comment: The sample project is already using the new annotations from `org.osgi.service.component.annotations`. But you've just made me realize that the documentation referencing `maven-scr-plugin` is outdated.

Comment: yeah, can you try replacing mvn-scr-plugin with maven-bundle-plugin and check if the issue shows up.

Answer (score -1):

The problem goes away if these two empty entries are added to the `core/pom.xml`:

```
                    <Export-Package></Export-Package>
                    <Private-Package></Private-Package>
```